# Swift UILongPressGesture on Button or Switch

Tags: swift, ios8

I'm trying to find out if what I press with UILongPressGesture is a button or switch in the function delete

```
 func delete() {
    let subviews = self.view.subviews as [UIView]
    for v in subviews {
        if let button = v as? UIButton {
           println("button")
        }
        else if let loadSwitch = v as? UISwitch {
           println("switch")
        }
   }
```

I have as a print button and switch

I had no problems when I was only the buttons but now that I have integrated the switch ...

PS the longpress on the switch I get it only if I press just below the switch itself

Answer (score 0):

You can check which type your UIViews are by using `isKindOfClass`

```
for v in subviews {
    if(v.isKindOfClass(UIButton)){
        //Do button stuff
    }else if(v.isKindOfClass(UISwitch)){
        //Do switch stuff
    }
}
```

But now there's still the problem with the switch. The problem is, that the `UILonGestureRecognizer` won't get called, because other UISwitch-actions fire up before. But you can stop that by using the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate-method `shouldReceiveTouch`:

```
class test:UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{

    func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        //If it's your switch, the normal gesture won't be called.
        if(touch.view == yourSwitch){
            return false
        }else{
            return true
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: but i have let gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer() in the class or i add the let gestureRecognize = UIGestureRecognize ?

Comment: You don't have to add a gesturerecognize. It's only a delegate.

Comment: i have error : fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value on if(touch.view == newSwitch)

Comment: Make your Switch global.

Comment: I followed your advice but I arrived at This point and don't go   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28331336/swift-uigesturerecognizerdelegate-dont-go-on-uiswitch PLEASE

Comment: i have add var newSwitch = UISwitch() but shouldReceiveTouch don't go